# Soundcloud /resolve endpoint broken?

Tags: ruby, soundcloud

Soundcloud Resolve endpoint returns "SoundCloud::ResponseError: SoundCloud::ResponseError", even with the test case given in the documentation.

```
require 'soundcloud'

#create client with your app's credentials 
client = Soundcloud.new(:client_id => 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID')

# a permalink to a track 
track_url = 'http://soundcloud.com/forss/voca-nomen-tuum'

# resolve track URL into track resource 
track = client.get('/resolve', :url => track_url)

# result: "SoundCloud::ResponseError: SoundCloud::ResponseError"
```

Other endpoints work fine. Am I missing something, or is this down?

Answer (score 2):

First thing is to check the endpoint directly. This works fine in the browser:

http://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?url=http://soundcloud.com/forss/voca-nomen-tuum&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID

The problem is somewhere in the code.

Comment: good find. You are correct the endpoint works. Looks like it's an issue with the Ruby client.

Comment: You could also track API endpoint changes with a free tool like API Patrol so you can prepare for it appropriately and get a notification in time.